# Low pass filter generalization in c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, signal-processing

Supposing I have a c# list with three **random numbers** `x ->200...300`,  `y->100...150` and `z->100..300` as elements as entry something like `rows=200 and cols=3`

```
x   y   z 
210 106 220
200 120 134
220 150 230
280 120 136
204 110 270
260 120 184
209 110 209
210 110 134
...
```

I was reading that A low pass filter is simply smoothing of the results to remove the high frequencies.  The simplest low pass filter is a box filter which is done by averaging n samples together. For averaging 2 samples together this is as simple as doing:

```
sample[n] (sample[n] + sample[n + 1]) / 2;
```

So, How would I apply low passfilter to these data?

do I need to apply `sample[n] (sample[n] + sample[n + 1]) / 2;` for each cell on matrix or what to do?

I was reading that low pass and high pass filters  'cancel' or zero-out the frequencies above/below a threshold, but in this case what would be the best way to get threshold, I do not get it...

Could you please explain how to apply low pass filter to dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) of M data points is simple but fairly crude low pass filter which *smooths* the data. For each output data point you take the average of N input points, e.g. for N = 3:

```
for (i = 1; i < N - 1; ++i)
{
    output[i] = (input[i - 1] + input[i] + input[i + 1]) / 3;
}
```

As you increase M you get more smoothing (because you're averaging more points) - another way of looking at this is that more of the high frequency components of your data (typically noise) are removed.

Note that the frequency response of such a moving average filter is fairly poor - it's find for some fairly simple tasks, such as filtering noise from time series data such as stock prices, but for more demanding applications we typically use a more sophisticated filter design.

A [high pass filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_pass_filter) is the complement of a low pass filter, in that it filters out the low frequency components. This includes the "steady state" (0 Hz) component, so typically the output will represent short term changes in the input.

A very crude high pass filter:

```
for (i = 1; i < N ; ++i)
{
    output[i] = input[i] - input[i - 1];
}
```

Comment: For taking high pass filter what could I use?

Comment: One question would be, I need to apply this formula to every vector right? , like applying first to x, then y and finally z columns is it correct?

Comment: Yes, if you have 3 independent data series (e.g. x, y, z accelerometer data) then you would filter each series separately.

Comment: While these filters are, indeed, "crude," that does not by any means mean that they aren't useful. eg. the US 4 week moving average unemployment figures are among the most closely watched economic indicators.

Comment: Yes, they're definitely useful, especially for people like economists who don't have a lot of math/signal processing expertise.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the laymen's answer is a simple matter of slew rate as set by the RC or RCL time constant of the circuit. R and C being reactive means that the results will vary according to frequency. At whatever time period set by the frequency of occurrence (sample rate). It is simpler to look at only RC without L. But basically the voltage will not be allowed to change faster in time than that allowed by the RC time constant which is a transcendental function relating to time or frequency. Natural forces which cause the limiting SLEW rate seems never to be a topic of such discussions.

Answer (score 0):

[An Exponential Moving Average Infinite Impulse Response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing) (IIR) can achieve smoother results at a lower price than it's corresponding Finite Impulse Response (FIR) filter of the same magnitude would.

```
// smoothingFactor is between 0.0 (no smoothing) and 0.9999.. (almost smoothing to DC) - *kind* of the inverse of cutoff frequency
void EMAIIRSmoothSignal(float[] input, float[] output, int N, float smoothingFactor = 0.8f)
{
    // forward EMA IIR
    float acc = input[0];
    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        acc = lerp(input[i], acc, smoothingFactor);
        output[i] = acc;
    }

    // backward EMA IIR - required only if we need to preserve the phase (aka make the filter symetric) - we usually want this
    acc = input[N - 1];
    for (i = N - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        acc = lerp(input[i], acc, smoothingFactor);
        output[i] = acc;
    }
}
```

Since the algo is fast (as all IIR filters are), we can apply the smoothing function twice of three times without much cost in order to achieve an almost Gaussian smoothing and better cutoff frequency roll-off.

Also, if we need the smoothingFactor to be computed based on an actual frequency (thus in linear terms), [this Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing#Time_constant) tells the relation between the smoothing value and it's linear term.